# What is the word for the opposite of a monolithic web app?

Tags: web-applications, architecture, terminology, semantics

I am talking about a web app that separates resources between a self contained client app (single page app) and a server side RESTful API.

I am thinking polylithic but that doesn't seem to be used in this context.

Comment: offtopic. not really a programming question. but offhand, "modular"?

Comment: Thankyou, I just want to be able to communicate effectively with other developers.

Answer (score 1):

The correct term I was looking for is 'micro-services' application. This style could be applied to any area of development including enterprise applications. But it particularly applies to web applications where you are likely to need a repeatable process capable of running concurrently. And in complex web apps you need different types of these concurrent processes.

Further information here:
http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html